# Android There is a issue parsing the package on gingerbread

Tags: android

I'm developing an android project , my app is running fine on lollipop but have a parsing problem in gingerbread despite of the fact that I have declared the minSdkversion=5.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: What editor are you using? how are you compiling the APK?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing problem" ? Can you post either a crash log, a compilation error, the logcat of the installation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use android-studio, than you should declare the min sdk-version in the gradle file instead of the android manifest.